# POST 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED) with flask (python and vuejs)

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, cors, axios

I am trying to post but I'm getting ERROR 405 method not allowed.
My server is running pretty good. Are there some more details needed to be added in python?

This is my python code using flask.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
api = Api(app)


class HelloWorld(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world'}

api.add_resource(HelloWorld, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and in vue code is,

```
axios({
                            method: 'post',
                            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/',
                            data: {
                                name: this.name,
                                description: this.description
                            },
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                            },
                        })
                        .then(function (response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                    });
```

Comment: You are doing a POST but you only implemented GET.

Comment: I did that now I'm getting this error, `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` @Klaus D

Comment: For a new problem, do a research for similar questions on Stack Overflow. If you don't find any, open a new question.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are requesting "POST" from front-end while trying to hit the url to access that view. and you have not defined any methods as post.

try to hit as 'get' or define a 'post' method in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Try expanding your class to include a POST method as well, e. g.

```
def post(self, name, description):
    return {'hello': 'world'}
```

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`  Now I'm getting this error. How do I give permission to access.@wogsland